# Problem testing material-ui datagrid with react-testing-library

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, material-ui, react-testing-library

I want to test the content of my material-ui datagrid but only the first 3 columns (out of 8) are rendered in the test. I can test the content of these 3 columns, no problem with that.
Everything renders correctly on a web browser.

My best guess is that's it due to the width and height of the rendered datagrid as these warnings say, but I haven't been able to find a solution in the docs.

```
Material-UI: useResizeContainer - The parent of the grid has an empty width.
You need to make sure the container has an intrinsic width.
The grid displays with a width of 0px.

You can find a solution in the docs:
https://material-ui.com/components/data-grid/rendering/#layout

Material-UI: useResizeContainer - The parent of the grid has an empty height.
You need to make sure the container has an intrinsic height.
The grid displays with a height of 0px.

You can find a solution in the docs:
https://material-ui.com/components/data-grid/rendering/#layout
```

It could also be due to the mount function : (According to the material-ui docs, you should use enzyme's mount function as argument for the createMount function, but I am using react 17 and the official enzyme adapter is not out yet. I tried with @wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17 but it didn't change anything. I am currently using 'render' from @testing-library/react)

```
const mount = createMount({mount:render})
```

Here is a simpler version of my component :

```
import React from "react";
import { DataGrid } from '@material-ui/data-grid';
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";


const Gridtest = (props) => {

const columns = [
    {field: 'id', headerName: 'ID', type: 'number',headerAlign: 'left', width: 130 },
    {field: 'tenant_id', headerName: 'Tenant ID', type: 'number',headerAlign: 'left', width: 130 },
    {field: 'user_reference', headerName: 'Customer user reference', type: 'string',headerAlign: 'left', width: 250 },
    {field: 'provider_name', headerName: 'Provider name', type: 'string',headerAlign: 'left', width: 220 },
    {field: 'provider_id', headerName: 'Provider ID', type: 'number',headerAlign: 'left', width: 130 },
    {field: 'expiration_date', headerName: 'Expiration date', type: 'dateTime',headerAlign: 'left', width: 220 },
    {field: 'last_start', headerName: 'Last start date', type: 'dateTime',headerAlign: 'left', width: 130 },
    {field: 'Action',
        headerName: 'Action',
        headerAlign: 'left',
        width: 100,
        renderCell: (params) => {
            return (
                <div>
                    <Button variant="contained" size="small" color="primary" disableRipple
                            onClick={() => null}>
                        Details
                    </Button>
                </div>
            )
        },
    },
];

const rows = [
    {
        "id": "10190",
        "tenant_id": "12201",
        "user_reference": "Xuser_ref",
        "provider_name": "Xprovider",
        "provider_id": "122",
        "expiration_date": "2020-04-07T17:36:40+02:00",
        "last_start": "2020-07-06T17:36:40+02:00"

    },
    {
        "id": "23541",
        "tenant_id": "96542",
        "user_reference": "Yuser_ref",
        "provider_name": "Yprovider",
        "provider_id": "856",
        "expiration_date": "2010-07-07T17:36:40+02:00",
        "last_start": "2010-09-06T17:36:40+02:00"

    }]

return(
    <main>
        <div style={{ display: 'flex', height: '100%',width: '100%', flexGrow: 1 }}>
            <DataGrid style={{height: '100%', width: '100%'}} autoHeight rows={rows} columns={columns} pageSize={5} checkboxSelection={false} hideFooterSelectedRowCount/>
        </div>
    </main>
)};

export default Gridtest;
```

The test file for my simpler component (the test succeeds) :

```
import {screen, render, act, findByTestId} from '@testing-library/react'
import React from 'react'
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect'
import Gridtest from '../../src/Gridtest'
import { createMount } from '@material-ui/core/test-utils';

describe('grid test', () => {

    const mount = createMount({mount:render})

    test('grid render', async () => {
        await act(async () => {
            mount(
                <Gridtest />
            );
        });
        expect(await screen.findByRole('grid')).toBeInTheDocument()
        expect(await screen.findAllByRole('columnheader')).toHaveLength(3)
        screen.debug(await screen.findByRole('grid'))
    })
})
```

screen.debug(await screen.findByRole('grid')) returns :

```
<div
  aria-colcount="8"
  aria-label="grid"
  aria-multiselectable="false"
  aria-rowcount="2"
  class="MuiDataGrid-root MuiDataGrid-root"
  role="grid"
  style="width: 0px; height: 175px;"
  tabindex="0"
>
  <div />
  <div
    class="MuiDataGrid-mainGridContainer"
  >
    <div
      class="MuiDataGrid-columnsContainer"
      style="min-height: 56px; max-height: 56px; line-height: 56px;"
    >
      <div
        aria-rowindex="1"
        class="MuiDataGrid-colCellWrapper scroll"
        role="row"
        style="transform: translate3d(-0px, 0, 0); min-width: 1310px;"
      >
        <div
          aria-colindex="1"
          class="MuiDataGrid-colCell MuiDataGrid-colCellSortable MuiDataGrid-colCellNumeric"
          data-field="id"
          role="columnheader"
          style="width: 130px; min-width: 130px; max-width: 130px;"
          tabindex="-1"
        >
          <div
            class="MuiDataGrid-colCell-draggable"
            draggable="false"
          >
            <div
              class="MuiDataGrid-colCellTitleContainer"
            >
              <div
                aria-label="ID"
                class="MuiDataGrid-colCellTitle"
                title=""
              >
                ID
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div
            class="MuiDataGrid-columnSeparator"
            style="min-height: 56px; opacity: 1;"
          >
            <svg
              aria-hidden="true"
              class="MuiSvgIcon-root MuiDataGrid-iconSeparator"
              focusable="false"
              viewBox="0 0 24 24"
            >
              <path
                d="M11 19V5h2v14z"
              />
            </svg>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div
          aria-colindex="2"
          class="MuiDataGrid-colCell MuiDataGrid-colCellSortable MuiDataGrid-colCellNumeric"
          data-field="tenant_id"
          role="columnheader"
          style="width: 130px; min-width: 130px; max-width: 130px;"
          tabindex="-1"
        >
          <div
            class="MuiDataGrid-colCell-draggable"
            draggable="false"
          >
            <div
              class="MuiDataGrid-colCellTitleContainer"
            >
              <div
                aria-label="Tenant ID"
                class="MuiDataGrid-colCellTitle"
                title=""
              >
                Tenant ID
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div
            class="MuiDataGrid-columnSeparator"
            style="min-height: 56px; opacity: 1;"
          >
            <svg
              aria-hidden="true"
              class="MuiSvgIcon-root MuiDataGrid-iconSeparator"
              focusable="false"
              viewBox="0 0 24 24"
            >
              <path
                d="M11 19V5h2v14z"
              />
            </svg>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div
          aria-colindex="3"
          class="MuiDataGrid-colCell MuiDataGrid-colCellSortable"
          data-field="user_reference"
          role="columnheader"
          style="width: 250px; min-width: 250px; max-width: 250px;"
          tabindex="-1"
        >
          <div
            class="MuiDataGrid-colCell-draggable"
            draggable="false"
          >
            <div
              class="MuiDataGrid-colCellTitleContainer"
            >
              <div
                aria-label="Customer user reference"
                class="MuiDataGrid-colCellTitle"
                title=""
              >
                Customer user reference
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div
            class="MuiDataGrid-columnSeparator"
            style="min-height: 56px; opacity: 1;"
          >
            <svg
              aria-hidden="true"
              class="MuiSvgIcon-root MuiDataGrid-iconSeparator"
              focusable="false"
              viewBox="0 0 24 24"
            >
              <path
                d="M11 19V5h2v14z"
              />
            </svg>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div
          class="MuiDataGrid-cell MuiDataGrid-cellLeft"
          role="cell"
          style="min-width: 800px; max-width: 800px; line-height: 55px; min-height: 56px; max-height: 56px;"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div
      class="MuiDataGrid-window"
      style="top: 56px; overflow-y: hidden;"
    >
      <div
        class="MuiDataGrid-dataContainer data-container"
        style="min-height: 119px; min-width: 1310px;"
      >
        <div
          class="MuiDataGrid-viewport"
          style="min-width: 0; max-width: 0; min-height: 104px; max-height: 104px;"
        >
          <div
            class="rendering-zone"
            style="max-height: 275px; width: 1310px; pointer-events: unset; transform: translate3d(-0px, -0px, 0);"
          >
            <div
              aria-rowindex="2"
              aria-selected="false"
              class="MuiDataGrid-row Mui-even"
              data-id="10190"
              data-rowindex="0"
              role="row"
              style="max-height: 52px; min-height: 52px;"
            >
              <div
                aria-colindex="0"
                class="MuiDataGrid-cell MuiDataGrid-cellRight"
                data-field="id"
                data-rowindex="0"
                data-value="10190"
                role="cell"
                style="min-width: 130px; max-width: 130px; line-height: 51px; min-height: 52px; max-height: 52px;"
                tabindex="0"
              >
                10190
              </div>
              <div
                aria-colindex="1"
                class="MuiDataGrid-cell MuiDataGrid-cellRight"
                data-field="tenant_id"
                data-rowindex="0"
                data-value="12201"
                role="cell"
                style="min-width: 130px; max-width: 130px; line-height: 51px; min-height: 52px; max-height: 52px;"
                tabindex="-1"
              >
                12201
              </div>
              <div
                aria-colindex="2"
                class="MuiDataGrid-cell MuiDataGrid-cellLeft"
                data-field="user_reference"
                data-rowindex="0"
                data-value="Xuser_ref"
                role="cell"
                style="min-width: 250px; max-width: 250px; line-height: 51px; min-height: 52px; max-height: 52px;"
                tabindex="-1"
              >
                Xuser_ref
              </div>
              <div
                class="MuiDataGrid-cell MuiDataGrid-cellLeft"
                role="cell"
                style="min-width: 800px; max-width: 800px; line-height: 51px; min-height: 52px; max-height: 52px;"
              />
            </div>
            <div
              aria-rowindex="3"
              aria-selected="false"
              class="MuiDataGrid-row Mui-odd"
              data-id="23541"
              data-rowindex="1"
              role="row"
              style="max-height: 52px; min-height: 52px;"
            >
              <div
                aria-colindex="0"
                class="MuiDataGrid-cell MuiDataGrid-cellRight"
                data-field="id"
                data-rowindex="1"
                data-value="23541"
                role="cell"
                style="min-width: 130px; max-width: 130px; line-height: 51px; min-height: 52px; max-height: 52px;"
                tabindex="-1"
              >
                23541
              </div>
              <div
                aria-colindex="1"
                class="MuiDataGrid-cell MuiDataGrid-cellRight"
                data-field="tenant_id"
                data-rowindex="1"
                data-value="96542"
                role="cell"
                style="min-width: 130px; max-width: 130px; line-height: 51px; min-height: 52px; max-height: 52px;"
                tabindex="-1"
              >
                96542
              </div>
              <div
                aria-colindex="2"
                class="MuiDataGrid-cell MuiDataGrid-cellLeft"
                data-field="user_reference"
                data-rowindex="1"
                data-value="Yuser_ref"
                role="cell"
                style="min-width: 250px; max-width: 250px; line-height: 51px; min-height: 52px; max-height: 52px;"
                tabindex="-1"
              >
                Yuser_ref
              </div>
              <div
                class="MuiDataGrid-cell MuiDataGrid-cellLeft"
                role="cell"
                style="min-width: 800px; max-width: 800px; line-height: 51px; min-height: 52px; max-height: 52px;"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div
      class="MuiDataGrid-footer"
    >
      <div />
      <div
        class="MuiTablePagination-root"
      >
        <div
          class="MuiToolbar-root MuiToolbar-regular MuiTablePagination-toolbar MuiToolbar-gutters"
        >
          <div
            class="MuiTablePagination-spacer"
          />
          <p
            class="MuiTypography-root MuiTablePagination-caption makeStyles-caption-1 MuiTypography-body2 MuiTypography-colorInherit"
          >
            1-2 of 2
          </p>
          <div
            class="MuiTablePagination-actions"
          >
            <button
              aria-label="Previous page"
              class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root MuiIconButton-colorInherit Mui-disabled Mui-disabled"
              disabled=""
              tabindex="-1"
              title="Previous page"
              type="button"
            >
              <span
                class="MuiIconButton-label"
              >
                <svg
                  aria-hidden="true"
                  class="MuiSvgIcon-root"
                  focusable="false"
                  viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                >
                  <path
                    d="M15.41 16.09l-4.58-4.59 4.58-4.59L14 5.5l-6 6 6 6z"
                  />
                </svg>
              </span>
            </button>
            <button
              aria-label="Next page"
              class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root MuiIconButton-colorInherit Mui-disabled Mui-disabled"
              disabled=""
              tabindex="-1"
              title="Next page"
              type="button"
            >
              <span
                class="MuiIconButton-label"
              >
                <svg
                  aria-hidden="true"
                  class="MuiSvgIcon-root"
                  focusable="false"
                  viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                >
                  <path
                    d="M8.59 16.34l4.58-4.59-4.58-4.59L10 5.75l6 6-6 6z"
                  />
                </svg>
              </span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: The sample code you posted has some problems. First, the component does not show where `columns` comes from, which is perhaps the most important detail to your question. Also, your test contains a lot of code that does not seem relevant to your question, such as mocking out an API, dealing with routing, and performing mutations. I suggest you write a much simpler component/test to demonstrate the problem, and also include the DOM (from [`screen.debug`](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-queries/#screendebug)).

Comment: I'm also annoyed by the warning messages about the DataGrid container having 0 width, and I am also using React Testing Library. It shouldn't matter which testing solution is used. The "grid has 0 width" technique smells like a hack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of a virtualization. you can disable it like

```
<Gridtest disableVirtualization />
```

Answer (score 26):

I have found a solution : you can set the columnBuffer prop of the datagrid.
For exemple `columnBuffer={8}` for 8 columns.

Comment: Yes, but I still get the MUI warning: "Material-UI: useResizeContainer - The parent of the grid has an empty width" in the logs, which obfuscate my test run outcomes.

Comment: @gap Looks like this was an issue with the package, if you update to a newer version it's fixed. The error is wrapped in some logic to test if the test environment is JSDOM

Comment: In the more recent version you can disable virtualisation entirely with the `disableVirtualization` prop. This forces the grid to render all cells. https://mui.com/components/data-grid/virtualization/#disable-virtualization

Answer (score 2):

It has nothing to do with DataGrid, make sure your exterior most container by default occupies 100% height and width. I was running into the same issue as shown below:

[image]

On reading the warnings, I realized that the container needs to be resized so I changed the CSS of my external most container to be a flexbox with the entire width as shown below:

```
{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

If you see my two images, you will notice the difference that was causing the table to fail from displaying properly.

[image]

Comment: this is correct answer

Answer (score 1):

You can also set up a global mock for this if you want to retain virtualization in your real data grid but turn it off for tests

```
import { DataGridPro as OriginalDataGridPro, DataGridProProps } from '@mui/x-data-grid-pro';

// Sets up a mock for disableVirtualization on DataGrid
// Allows tests to check all columns
// Explained by https://github.com/mui/mui-x/issues/1151

export * from '@mui/x-data-grid-pro';
export const DataGridPro = (props: DataGridProProps) => {
    return <OriginalDataGridPro {...props} disableVirtualization />;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else hits this page and is still getting the Material-UI: useResizeContainer: If you are using the happy-dom environment instead of jsdom, the following code in mui-x is the reason:

```
      // jsdom has no layout capabilities
      const isJSDOM = /jsdom/.test(window.navigator.userAgent);

      if (size.height === 0 && !errorShown.current && !props.autoHeight && !isJSDOM) {
        logger.error(
          [
            'The parent DOM element of the data grid has an empty height.',
            'Please make sure that this element has an intrinsic height.',
            'The grid displays with a height of 0px.',
            '',
            'More details: https://mui.com/r/x-data-grid-no-dimensions.',
          ].join('\n'),
        );
        errorShown.current = true;
      }
```

A workaround for this is to modify the useragent. If you are using vitest and happy-dom, as of happy-dom 12.0.0, this can be by adding the following to your vitest defineConfig to trick it:

```
    environmentOptions: {
      happyDOM: {
        settings: {
          // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
          // @ts-ignore
          navigator: {
            userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (linux) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) jsdom/22.1.0',
          },
        },
      },
    },
```

(The `@ts-ignore` is because at time of writing vitest doesn't include navigator.userAgent in its typing for happy-dom)

Hopefully mui-x will be updated to detect HappyDOM in the useragent string which is now added and the workaround won't be needed.